# Concatenation error (Wrong number of items passed x, placement implies 1)

Tags: pandas, error-handling, type-conversion, concatenation

I have a dataframe like so:

```
a            b
thing1      1.00
thing2      2.71
```

column a is string and column b is float64 and I am trying to convert the frame to where if column b is 1, then return 1 and if the value is above 1 in column b, return 2.71/6,2.71R24,1

```
a         b       c
thing1    1       1
thing2    2.71    2.71/6,2.71R24,1
```

I have tried a function like so

```
def convert (row):
    if row['b'] == 1.00:
        return '1' 
    else:
        return df['b'].astype(str)+'/6,'+df['b'].astype(str)+'R24,1'
df['c']  = df.apply(lambda row: convert (row), axis=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 15, placement implies 1
```

I can't seem to bypass this error?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `np.where`

```
df['c']=np.where(df.b==1,1,df.b.astype(str)+'/6,'+df.b.astype(str)+'R24,1')
df
Out[504]: 
        a     b                 c
0  thing1  1.00                 1
1  thing2  2.71  2.71/6,2.71R24,1
```

Comment: almost , just consider " value is above 1"